# Arrange collection along curve with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

After searching, I apologize in advance if this has been answered before. I would like to arrange a collection of different objects along a curve as follows:

[image]

I have tried the following Geometry Nodes:
[image]

Results in the following with all objects stacked together.
[image]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Geometry Nodes:

[image]

Since the option *Reset children* in the *Collection info* none removes all transformations, we let it off, that way we can keep the rotation. But now the positions should be set to $\left(0,0,0\right)$

After that we just align the rotation with the tanget and normal of the curve point.

Comment: That worked!  Thank You